# can't deserialize object from stream created from string

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I want to create method that serializes an object to file. Than I read file and get the content as String. I save the String in the database and than I read the string from DB and I De-serialize it to Object

I almost did it but I get error that `there is no map for object`

This is how I serialize object

```
public static String Serialize(Object toSerialize)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(100000, 1000000000);
        String fileName = randomNumber + ".txt";

        fileName = "EmployeeInfo.txt";

        Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, toSerialize);
        stream.Close();

        String fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        return fileContent;
    }
```

This is how I convert String to Stream for Deserialize

```
String serialized = Serializer.Serialize(user);

        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mStream);
        writer.Write(serialized);
        writer.Flush();
        mStream.Position = 0;
```

And now the deserialization

```
 public static Object Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        Object returnObject;
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        returnObject = (Object)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        return returnObject;
    }
```

Where am I making the mistake ? What should I make better to make it working ?

Comment: What's the object you want to serialize?

Comment: on which line you are getting error

Comment: You can not read a binary file with `ReadAllText`. Use `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filename))`

Comment: also Fixus, have you even explored looking at some of the `Related` topics located on the right hand side of this immediate page..?

Comment: @I4V that good but I have problem with deserialize from the string. `Stream has bad binary format. 41-41-45-41-41-......` any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer.

First of all thanks for @I4V for his comment:

This is my Serialize method

```
public static String Serialize(Object toSerialize)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(100000, 1000000000);
        String fileName = randomNumber + ".txt";

        fileName = "EmployeeInfo.txt";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, toSerialize);

        String fileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        stream.Close();

        return fileContent;
    }
```

And now method Deserialize that can Deserialize object from String

```
 public static Object Deserialize(String stringObject)
    {
        Object returnObject;
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringObject);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        returnObject = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);

        return returnObject;
    }
```

thats all